# When do you add vs multiply variances of normal random variables?

Tags: probability

Say we have a random normal variable $A\sim  \mathcal{N}(u_1, var_1)$.

Since we add variances when we add normal random variables (because $Var(A+A) = var(A) + var(A))$, the distribution of $A + A = \mathcal{N} \sim(2u_1, 2var_1)$.

However, if instead, I multiply A by the constant of 2. Say $Y = 2A$, then the distribution of $Y$ is $\mathcal{N}(2u_1, 4var_1)$. This obviously, is not the same as the distribution of $A+A$, but why not?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In the first case, $\operatorname{Var}(A+A)\ne \operatorname{Var}(A)+\operatorname{Var}(A)$. You need to add $2\operatorname{Cov}(A,A)=2\operatorname{Var}(A)$.

Comment: Don´t you accept answers anymore?

Answer (score 1):

First of all $A$ is not independent of $A$. If $A$ and $B$ two independent random variables then your variance additivity holds because of zero covariance term.