# Adding n standard normal RVs vs multiplying by n

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose $X$ and $X_1,X_2,..X_n$ are iid from a standard normal distribution.
Why is the distribution of $nX$ different from the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$?

Is there a convenient way of showing the difference graphically? I'm mainly focused on variance. I'm imagining adding multiple Z distributions on top of each other for  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$.
I'm imagining $nX$ would be like stretching a Z plot horizontally by a factor of $\sqrt n$. Do I have those plots correct?

I guess I'm struggling to understand why multiplying a scalar times a single instance of a random variable would not be the same as adding multiple iid random variables. I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754677/when-do-you-add-vs-multiply-variances-of-normal-random-variables) post and it helped some.

Here's what I've learned so far:

- $nX$ follows a  $N(0, n^2)$
  $$Var(nX) = E[(nX - E(nX)^2]$$
  $$= E[n^2X^2] + E[[E(nX)]^2] - 2E[E(nX)nX)]]$$
  $$=n^2E[X^2]+0+0$$
  $$=n^2[Var(X)+[E(X)]^2]$$
  $$=n^2Var(X)$$
  $$=n^2$$
- $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$ follows $N(0,n)$
  $$Var(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}) =^{independence} \sum_{i=1}^{n}Var(X_i)$$
  $$=n$$

Is there any intuition about why adding n standard normal RVs would have less variance than multiplying a single rv by n?

Also, doesn't this suggest a relationship between adding $n$ standard normals is equivalent to multiplying a single standard normal by $\sqrt{n}$? That's the Central Limit Theorem right?

Note: the second parameter in my normal notation is the variance $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: You can look at the general formula $Var(X_1+X_2)=Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)+2\cdot Cov(X_1,X_2)$. What happens if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent? What happens if $X_1=X_2$?

Comment: oh, that's a great point. I never realized that when $X_1  = X_2$ it clearly shows $Var(2X_1) = 4 Var(X_1)$. When they're independent the covariance term goes away. But it can never be both because $X_1$ is not independent from $X_1$. Thank you.

Comment: Your're welcome. That's true. $X_1$ fully depend on $X_1$, thus $Cov(X_1,X_1)=Var(X_1)$.